# Apache SPARK GroupByKey alternate

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have below columns in my table [col1,col2,key1,col3,txn_id,dw_last_updated]. Out of these txn_id , key1 are primary key columns. In my dataset I can have multiple records for the combination of (txn_id,key). Out of those records , I need to pick the latest one one based on dw_last_updated..

I'm using a logic this. I'm consistently hitting memory issue and I believe its partly because of groupByKey()... Is there a better alternate for this ?

```
case class Fact(col1: Int,
  col2: Int,
  key1: String,
  col3: Int,
  txn_id: Double,
  dw_last_updated: Long)

sc.textFile(s3path).map { row =>
          val parts = row.split("\t")
          Fact(parts(0).toInt,
            parts(1).toInt,
            parts(2),
            parts(3).toInt,
            parts(4).toDouble,
            parts(5).toLong)
        }).map { t => ((t.txn_id, t.key1), t) }.groupByKey(512).map {
          case ((txn_id, key1), sequence) =>
            val newrecord = sequence.maxBy {
              case Fact_Cp(col1, col2, key1, col3, txn_id, dw_last_updated) => dw_last_updated.toLong
            }
           (newrecord.col1 + "\t" + newrecord.col2 + "\t" + newrecord.key1 +
              "\t" + newrecord.col3 + "\t" + newrecord.txn_id + "\t" + newrecord.dw_last_updated)
        }
```

Appreciate your thoughts / suggestions...

Comment: Looks good to me, I'm afraid. You could try more partitions. But maybe you just need more machines.

Comment: It this still unresolved?

Answer (score 1):

`rdd.groupByKey` collects all values per key, requiring the necessary memory to hold the sequence of values for a key on a single node. Its use is discouraged. See [[1]](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/rdd/PairRDDFunctions.scala#L433).

Given that we are interested in only 1 value per key: max(dw_last_updated), a more memory efficient way would be to use `rdd.reduceByKey` where the reduce function here is to pick up the max of the two records for the same key using that timestamp as discriminant.

```
rdd.reduceByKey{case (record1,record2) => max(record1, record2)}
```

Applied to your case, it should look like this:

```
case class Fact(...)
object Fact {
  def parse(s:String):Fact = ???
  def maxByTs(f1:Fact, f2:Fact):Fact = if (f1.dw_last_updated.toLong > f2.dw_last_updated.toLong) f1 else f2
}
val factById = sc.textFile(s3path).map{row => val fact = Fact.parse(row); ((fact.txn_id, fact.key1),fact)}
val maxFactById = factById.reduceByKey(Fact.maxByTs)
```

Note that I've defined utility operations on the `Fact` companion object to keep the code tidy. I also advice to give named variables to each transformation step or logical group of steps. It makes it the program more readable.

Comment: could you please elaborate your answer ? How do I get to (record1,record2) ?

Comment: have a look at the added example - but don't get used to it :-)